# Different behavior of dynamically created text fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a set of text fields that when I click on, the text disappears and comes back when blurred (classic form behavior), and a button that when you click on, you have a jQuery modal window. However, I wanted to allow the user to add more text fields (and buttons) with jQuery. the problem is, the fields that my users add don't behave the same way as the static ones. For instance, when I click on the button (the one added by user), the modal doesn't appear.
Here is my code to give you a better idea :

```
<form method="post" action="payment.php">
    <div id="formulaire">
        <div class="formelements">
            <input type="text" name="from" value="Ex: English(UK)" style="width:100px;margin-right:0px;"
            class="langfield">
            <div class="droparrow" id="arrow"></div>
            <input type="text" name="from" value="Ex: French(FR)" style="width:100px;margin-right:0px;"
            class="langfield">
            <div class="droparrow"></div>
            <input type="text" name="nopages" id="nopages" value="Ex:4">
            <div class="uploadbtn"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and this is my javascript code to change the behavior of the fields :

```
$('.formelements input').each(function () {
    var default_value = this.value;
    $(this).focus(function () {
        if (this.value == default_value) {
            this.value = '';
            $(this).css("font-weight", "bold");
            $(this).css("color", "#323232");
        }
    });
    $(this).blur(function () {
        if (this.value == '') {
            this.value = default_value;
            $(this).css("font-weight", "normal");
            $(this).css("color", "#9e9e9e");
        }
    });
});
/* Modals script start UPDATED AS REQUESTED  */
   $('#formelements').on("click", ".uploadbtn", function () {
    $("#modaldialog").dialog({
    height: 332,
    width: 625,
    modal: true
    });
   });
```

Thanks a lot for your help in advance !!

Comment: Would it not be easier to use the [`placeholder`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute) attribute (and one of the many [existing shims](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js))?

Answer (score 1):

To fix the "no modal dialog" problem replace

```
$(".uploadbtn").click(function () {
    $("#modaldialog").dialog({
        height: 332,
        width: 625,
        modal: true
    });
});
```

with

```
$('.formelements').on("click", ".uploadbtn", function () {
    $("#modaldialog").dialog({
        height: 332,
        width: 625,
        modal: true
    });
});
```

This uses the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function which will work for newly created DOM elements. You could replace `#formelements` with any parent element thats present on load - the form could be used here

### Note

The `on()` method requires at least jQuery 1.7 to work ... if you have a previous version you can use [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) :

```
$('.formelements').delegate(".uploadbtn", "click", function () {
    $("#modaldialog").dialog({
        height: 332,
        width: 625,
        modal: true
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this and I can't add more elements dynamically,and the static buttons doesn't work (can't show the modal)

Comment: @MohamedTurki what errors are you getting ? any errors on load ? is your HTML different from your question ? where are you adding the "button" which is actually a `div` ....

Comment: In fact, the upload "button" is actually a div with the class "uploadbtn", you can see it in my original post. here is the error i'm getting :
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'

Comment: @MohamedTurki can you update your question with your new JavaScript - sounds like you are trying to execute `on()` on a non-jQuery object

Comment: @MohamedTurki OK my screw up ... change `#formelements` to `.formelements` its a class not an id !!! sorry

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @DavidThomas i was just updating my answer with required jquery version and delegate as alternative ....i think the problem is the selector ...

Comment: @ManseUK Even when I updated it, I still have the original problem !

Comment: @MohamedTurki what version of jQuery are you using ? see my answer - if you are using <1.7 then you need to use delegate

Comment: The version i'm using is 1.8.

Comment: Oops ! Sorry I was looking at the Ui-library i think. I'm was using 1.5 sth, now I changed it to 1.7.2 same thing happens. The dynamically created form fields don't behave same as the others.